# ListBox with DataTemplate recognize SelectedItem

Tags: c#, .net-core, avaloniaui

I have a `ListBox` with a simple `DataTemplate`, a `CheckBox`, and a `TextBox`.
If the user checks a `CheckBox` I want to get this changed item, like the property `SelectedItem` of the `ListBox`.

How can I get the element from `List2`, which has changed?

`MyListItem`:

```
public class MyListItem2 : ReactiveObject
{

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _name, value, "Name");
        }
    }
    private bool _isMarked;
    public bool IsMarked
    {
        get { return _isMarked; }
        set
        {
            this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _isMarked, value, "IsMarked");
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
<Window xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataTemplate.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns:viewsmodels="clr-namespace:DataTemplate.ViewModels;assembly=DataTemplate"
        xmlns:dt="clr-namespace:DataTemplate;assembly=DataTemplate"
        Title="DataTemplate" Width="700">
<Window.DataContext>
  <viewsmodels:MainWindowViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid ColumnDefinitions="250">
  <ListBox Grid.Column="1" Items="{Binding List2}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="dt:MyListItem2">
        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="50*,50*">              
          <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" Content="Mark" IsChecked="{Binding IsMarked}"/>  
          <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}"/>  
        </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyListItem2> List2 { get; set; }    

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        List2 = new ObservableCollection<MyListItem2>();
        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < rand.Next(1, 20); i++)
        {
            MyListItem2 mli = new MyListItem2();
            mli.Name = "ListItem" + i;
            mli.IsMarked = false;
            mli.PropertyChanged += ItemChanged; 
            List2.Add(mli);
        }
    }
    private void ItemChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {            
        var item = sender as MyListItem2;
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("changed: {0} {1}", item.Name, item.IsMarked));            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see two ways:

- Since you are using MVVM, implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface on the MyListItem2 class ([Microsoft Reference on INotifyPropertyChanged implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification)). Raise the property change event when the IsMarked value is set/changed, then wire into the PropertyChanged event handler of the item to determine when it is changed. .  OR
- If you have codebehidn, add a "Checked" and/or "Unchecked" event handler on the checkbox itself from the XAML. Shown below.

  CheckBox Grid.Column="0" Content="Mark" IsChecked="{Binding IsMarked}"/>
        Checked="IsMarked_Checked"

Codebehind

```
public void IsMarked_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var ck = sender As Checkbox;

    if (ck == null) 
    {
         return;
    }

    // do whatever you need to here using the datacontext of the Checkbox
}
```

Comment: Sorry I updated te question. please note, that it is .net core and AvaloniaUI.

Comment: I take your first point and this works. I only need to route the PropertyChanged event to my ViewModel.
I updated my code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know when a check box is checked/unchecked by the user you will need to trigger on the event from the checkbox.

Use something like this:

```
private void MyCheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //check IsChecked of MyCheckBox here
}
```

Comment: Sorry I updated te question.
please note, that it is .net core and AvaloniaUI

Answer (score 0):

Try setting binding Mode:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Comment: I think the tricky part is, that when I change the text or the checkbox, the `SelectedItem` is not changing.